# The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

When running vite and Docker, I receive the following error (after execute docker compose up):

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "/goalManager". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
at packageEntryFailure (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:23266:11)
at resolvePackageEntry (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:23263:5)
at tryResolveFile (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:22884:38)
at tryFsResolve (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:22862:16)
at Context.resolveId (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:22731:24)
at Object.resolveId (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:43314:46)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ModuleGraph.resolveUrl (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:61580:26)
at async ModuleGraph.getModuleByUrl (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:61437:23)
at async doTransform (file:///goalManager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:41010:20)
```

package.json is below.

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vue-next": "~0.1.4"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

when vuetify comment out, error don't occur.
So vuetify might be the cause.

main.js is below.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import './style.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})


createApp(App).use(router, vuetify).mount('#app')
```

and vite.config.js is below.
i don't define vuetify setting.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
        '^/api': {
          target: process.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE,
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
      },
    },
})
```

How can I resolve error?